# Viewing Reporting Services Report in IE does not render report on some machines

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, rendering, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

Server 2008 R2 + SQL Standard 2008 R2

Reporting services configured & working, reports created with BIDS 2008 & uploaded as myReport.rdl

Now when I view the reports using IE9 on the ..Reports/Pages/Report.aspx URL the report renders correctly for me on my laptop (Win7 Pro x64)

On my colleges laptop (Win7 Pro x32) using exactly the same reporting services account he gets the loading wait screen then nothing, just blank, no report detail visible.

His laptop has had all 3 report viewers installed  2005, 2008 SP1 and 2010.

I've reset his IE9 settings back to the defaults but to no avail.

I can't fathom why its working for me on my laptop and not for him on his, his laptop must be missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the bottom bar for any script errors?

Try pressing F12 (or use the menu) to open the developer tools in IE9 and see compare the rendered page, is the content there or hidden? Did it even load the content?

I think I remember something similar where a user had chosen a different option for intranet settings that caused similar behaviour. Check the zone the browser is putting the page into and double check the settings.

Comment: I'll give it a go, thanks.  The user has gone on leave for 2 weeks so I'll test and update the question when they are back and I can verify.